# How to do a check on a specific element in an array property in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to optimize my code that I'm currently running on a node server.
The part of the code that I'm trying to optimize is code related with filtering something called "content" part of it's schema is

```js
const contentSchema = new Schema({
title: String , 
skills :[
{
skillId:ObjectId , 
skillLevel:Int
}]
})
```

I'm trying to filter it by the difficulty. each content's difficulty is based on the skill with the highest level. so if the skill with the highest level is 5 then the content difficulty is 5.
How I'm currently doing it.

```js
const content = await Content.find({
...someOtherFilters
}).lean()
content = content.map((content)=> {
const difficulty = content.skills.reduce((acc , curr)=> {
if (!acc || curr.skillLevel > acc) return curr.skillLevel
return acc 
} , 0)
return {
...content, 
difficulty
}
}).filter(({difficulty})=> {
return difficulty === desiredDifficulty
})
```

How can I convert this into some mongodb query that I can then use like this

```
const contentCount = await Cotnent.countDocuments(contentQuery)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mapping and filtering can be done using [`aggregate`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/).

By using `$max` you can find which element in the `skills` array has the highest `skillLevel` and use `$arrayElemAt` to pluck it from the array. You can then use `$set` to set the `difficulty` to the value of that `skillLevel`.

With this new `difficulty` property you can use `$match` to find documents that match your `desiredDifficulty` criteria.

Something like this I think might help:

```js
const content = await Content.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      difficulty: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$skills",
          {
            $indexOfArray: [
              "$skills.skillLevel",
              {
                $max: "$skills.skillLevel"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "difficulty": "$difficulty.skillLevel"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      difficulty: desiredDifficulty
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NTWn_p4S1zM) for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @jQuenny is correct and can be simplified to :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [{$max: "$skills.skillLevel"}, desiredDifficulty]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Kmq8TVVCOAy)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calculating the maximum difficulty on the fly, it would be best to store it as a property on the document, e.g. `maxDifficulty`. It should be updated whenever a new skill is added to the document. You will have very simple queries afterwards and you can support them by creating an index on the new property, e.g.:

```
{
  maxDifficulty: 4
}
```

For updating existing documents, you can use an aggregation pipeline similar to the following ([mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yCRYDfBV16g) - thank you @jQueeny for the documents in your playground):

```
[
  {
    $set: {
      maxDifficulty: {
        $first: {
          $sortArray: {
            input: "$skills.skillLevel",
            sortBy: -1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      // Define merge as required
    }
  } 
]
```

Please note that documents that do not contain any skills will not receive a `maxDifficulty` property. You can add an `$ifNull` operator when setting the field to set the `maxDifficulty` to 0 if needed.